# CircleCI upload to CodeCov cannot find coverage report?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, circleci, codecov

As TravisCI.org is no longer free for small open source projects, I am trying to setup CircleCI and CodeCov.

Creating the Coverage report in CircleCI seems to work:

[image]

But uploading to CodeCov fails, claming report cannot be found:
[image]

I followed the instructions at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/code-coverage/#codecov

- Used orb codecov/codecov@1.0.2
- Allowed unprivate orbs
- Using CircleCI 2.1
- Generating phpdbg
- I tried with store_artificats and without, unclear to me if this shall be used with codecov, but both fail

Thats my config.yml:

```
# PHP CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-php/
version: 2.1

orbs:
  codecov: codecov/codecov@1.0.2

# Define a job to be invoked later in a workflow.
# See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs
jobs:
  build:
    # Specify the execution environment. You can specify an image from Dockerhub or use one of our Convenience Images from CircleCI's Developer Hub.
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#docker-machine-macos-windows-executor
    docker:
      # Specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/php:7.2-node-browsers

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # Using the RAM variation mitigates I/O contention
      # for database intensive operations.
      # - image: circleci/mysql:5.7-ram
      #
      # - image: redis:2.8.19

    # Add steps to the job
    # See: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#steps
    steps:
      - checkout

      - run: sudo apt update # PHP CircleCI 2.0 Configuration File# PHP CircleCI 2.0 Configuration File sudo apt install zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install zip

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            # "composer.lock" can be used if it is committed to the repo
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: composer install -n --prefer-dist

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "composer.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./vendor

      # run tests with phpunit or codecept
      #- run: ./vendor/bin/phpunit

      - run:
          name: "Run tests"
          command: phpdbg -qrr vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html build/coverage-report
      - codecov/upload:
          file: build/coverage-report
```

Here is the failing build:

https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/iwasherefirst2/laravel-multimail/25/workflows/57e6a71c-7614-4a4e-a7cc-53f015b3d437/jobs/35

Comment: You can also add [`test metadata`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/#phpunit) so you can see what test failed in a better way (in CircleCI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codecov is not able to process HTML coverage reports. You should ask `phpunit` to output XML as well by either changing or appending your command to read `--coverage-clover coverage.xml`

You can view a list of the supported and unsupported coverage formats at https://docs.codecov.com/docs/supported-report-formats

[1] Saved https://web.archive.org/web/20220113142241/https://docs.codecov.com/docs/supported-report-formats